# Google Cloud Storage folders list with PHP on App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have been trouble looking a solution to get listed of Google Cloud Storage Folders list with PHP on App Engine without using GCS PHP API.

- I know that there is PHP API for this...
- I know that it is only listing files when (readdir, opendir and other PHP dir methods) but skipped any folder...

Can somebody guide me with a tips, my question is that how do I get listed anything on a particular folder?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a 'folder' on GCS - it is a flat file system.

Folders are simulated in the UI + APIs but treating files with a '/' in the name as part of a folder structure.

That being said, the gcs stream wrapper provided with App Engine should support opendir(), readdir(), closedir() on a Cloud Storage bucket and make it look like it's listing a folder. How is this not working for you?

Comment: I agreed with the first and second paragraph... Like I have mention on my question opendir() only get the list of object that having extension.

Comment: so you want something like glob? you'll need to roll your own with opendir() and then using readdir() to filter the files you want.