# google cloud storage with php app engine. Get all sub directories list

Tags: google-cloud-storage, subdirectory

How would it be possible to get a list with all directories inside a specific directory of a Cloud Storage bucket using an App Engine application in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can try two approaches to list all the directories inside a specific directory in a bucket:

1. Use the code snippet from the [PHP docs samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/src/list_objects_with_prefix.php#L36) at Google Cloud Platform GitHub and modify it in a way that `list_objects_with_prefix` function includes also `delimiter`, not only `prefix`. I have written such function in Python in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198056/is-it-possible-to-query-google-cloud-storage-similar-to-using-ls-command-in-te) SO topic, you can use it as a reference. Here `prefix` needed to be the name of the parent directory, for e.g. `'my_directory/'` and `delimiter` is simply `'/'` to indicate that we want to end our search on elements finishing with '/' (hence, directories).
2. Use [gsutil ls command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls) to list objects in a directory from within PHP. You will need to use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function:

   ```php
   $execCommand = "gsutil ls gs://bucket";
   $output = shell_exec($execCommand);
   ```

`output` will be a string in this case and it will contain also file names if present in the parent directory.

[This SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728743/google-cloud-storage-folders-list-with-php-on-app-engine?rq=1) might be also informative, here the question was to list the whole directory (together with files).